# python google-cloud-storage library does not pick active user-account

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I am using [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) tutorial to connect my GCS. I have multiple account with google and activated one with `gcloud auth login` and I double checked with `gcloud auth list` and it shows both accounts but one I need is marked with `ACTIVE`. But when I try to run the code mentioned in tutorial, getting following error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=<myproject>&projection=noAcl: <INACTIVE USER ACCOUNT> does not have storage.buckets.list access to project <PROJECT-ID>.
```

I don't know why it is picking up inactive account instead of active account. am I missing something here? Please help

Even I revoked inactive account using command `gcloud auth revoke --account`, still python scripts referring that account only and throwing the same error.

PS - I am using Anaconda3.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue, It got resolved by exporting env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with a value pointing to the path of your bucket credentials JSON file eg.

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/myuser/Downloads/googleCredentials.json`

This command basically sets default account credentials. This  Hope it helps you too.

Comment: yes I can do that. but my question is from where it is picking up that account?

Comment: This google document talks in detail about how default account gets picked https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials